# Possible to use TestFlight to distribute and test an application without paid iOS membership?

Tags: ios, testflight

Is it possible to distribute (to a handful of users) an iOS application using TestFlight without having a paid iOS developer membership?  The testers have iOS devices but would need to be able to download the application (they won't be able to hook their devices up to my development machine).

Comment: Hi There, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, as it is not a specific question about programming, but rather about using TestFlight to bypass app distribution. You may have better luck contacting TestFlight's support email.

Comment: But the answe is no, TestFlight requires a paid membership of the Apple Developer Program